# LaunchScreen can't load image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, launch-screen

I've used LaunchScreen in the program，added a UIImageView and a Label,  but sometimes the UIImageView can show the image and sometimes it does not show, why?

Icon on the device will not display in the simulator can be displayed
[image]

Comment: provide more informatoin, screenshots?

Comment: you set image for uiimageview is url or uiimage in bundel?

Comment: Do you forget 2x or 3x images?

Comment: There is little to no information here. You need to add more information like a screenshot of the storyboard etc... Are you trying to load the image in code? Etc...

Comment: 2x or 3x images are all there.

Comment: Try to reset your simulator?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the version of xcode that you're using. I faced the same issue and I fixed it by creating new .xib file and setting the new file as the launchscreen in the info.plist file. It might be a bug from the xcode.

Comment: xcode version 7.2. I do as you say, or not. I am very confused.

Comment: I had same problem with the same version of the xcode. Please try my above mentioned step

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:
(1) Drag your image to the main part of your project not in the image assets folder see pic arrow on top left
(2) Then select the imageview in the launch screen
(3) Pick the image with the .png extension not the image without the extension since that is the image in the assets folder
(4) Viola!
(5) The problem is people are picking an image from the assets folder and that will not show up in launch screen
(6) See picture
[image]